# Left edge of the display doubles over randomly. Why, and how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, troubleshooting

this is a very new problem, and it is very strange, i do not know how to explain it, or how to find a solution for it.

if it has already been resolved, than i am sorry but i don't even know how to look for this.

the basic description is this.

the left side of my display, at the edge of the screen (a vertical strip, 1 cm wide.. roughly ) copies over on to the next 1 cm wide strip of the display ...

[image]

also, sometimes when scrolling with the mouse wheel, the section of the screen my mouse hovers over (a 1 cm, roughly, wide strip), desyncs with the rest of the screen and lags behind momentarily. but not as often as the main problem

...

context wise, this is a laptop , connected to a flat screen tv (laptop screen turned of, tv acts as main display), with a Windows 7 Ultimate edition.

...

if this is not the correct place to ask this sort of question, than please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Best guess is that Windows has failed to recognise the display correctly.  In Windows 7, go to Start => Devices and Printers and check the device name against the actual TV you have.

Comment: Have you set the TV to "PC" mode? Disabled all "make the picture look better" features in the TV menus?